# Install Tensorflow 2.0 in conda enviroment

Tags: python, tensorflow, conda

I would like to know if anyone knows how can I install tensorflow==2.0.0-alpha0 in a conda enviroment using python 3.7. Is it possible to use python 3.7 or do I have to downgrade to 3.6. Either way what is the command I need to use because the following don't find any package

```
conda install tensorflow==2.0.0-alpha0
conda install tensorflow 
conda install tensorflow=2.0.0-alpha0
```

I am using fedora 29 and conda 4.6.8
Thanks!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It could be the case that the package version you want is not available in conda-forge. What you could do is install packages with pip in your conda environment.

```
pip install tensorflow==2.0.0-alpha0
```

Also the requirements don't state python 3.7, you can try your luck or downgrade to python 3.6.

Comment: Thanks! That worked with python 3.7. Although I am bit concerned whether it is a good to use two package distributions, in this case pip inside conda

Comment: Glad it worked! There could be issues with using pip and conda simultaneously. But in my experience I never had troubles. If you want more info the makers of anaconda have a nice blogpost about this https://www.anaconda.com/using-pip-in-a-conda-environment/ .

Comment: Have you tried `pip install tensorflow-gpu==2.0.0-alpha0`? This will install the gpu version. The one in the answer is the cpu version.

Comment: Update: The new beta version is available by the command `pip install tensorflow==2.0.0-beta1`. The Anaconda documentation recommends to first install all packages by conda first, and then use the so-called upgrade strategy, i.e. use `pip install --upgrade tensorflow==2.0.0-beta1`

Answer (score 36):

### TENSORFLOW 2.0 release version is out!

Since 01/10/2019 I'm not talking beta but the release version.

### Using Anaconda

Since 01/11/2019 Anaconda is supporting the Tensorflow 2.0.0.

**Option 1:** For what the easiest way is just:

`conda install tensorflow` or `conda install tensorflow-gpu`

For the gpu mode, anaconda will take care of all the CUDA everything you need to install for the tensorflow gpu mode to work so I strongly recommend using this method.

The only issue with this method is that anaconda might not have the last last version of TensorFlow. For example, at Feb 21 2021, conda has the version 2.3 whereas the PIP version is 2.4. You can check the current version of [gpu](https://anaconda.org/anaconda/tensorflow-gpu) or [cpu](https://anaconda.org/anaconda/tensorflow).

**Option 2 (virtual env):** It is [strongly recommended](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip#2.-create-a-virtual-environment-recommended) to use an environment on where to install tensorflow, for which you need the following command that will create an environment first and then install tensorflow within:

- CPU: `conda create -n <your_env_name> tensorflow`
- [GPU](https://medium.com/@shaolinkhoa/install-tensorflow-gpu-2-0-alpha-on-anaconda-for-windows-10-ubuntu-ced099010b21): `conda create -n <your_env_name> tensorflow-gpu`

Change `<your_env_name>` by a meaningful name like `tf-2`

To use tensorflow run first `conda activate <your_env_name>`

### Using pip

Using pip the tensorflow [official instructions](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip) are quite complete.

Just install tensorflow using pip like:

```
# Current stable release for CPU-only
pip install tensorflow
```

I yet recommend before doing everything to install tensorflow in a new environment so the 3 steps would be (with anaconda):

```
conda create --n <our_env_name> pip
conda activate <your_env_name>
pip install tensorflow
```

Now for the GPU version it's harder with pip, I recommend you this [link](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/gpu) that explains the extra things you need to install (CUDA and others).

Comment: Tensorflow 2 is now on conda. `conda install tensorflow`

Comment: For me, `conda install tensorflow` installs tensorflow 1.13.2. Getting the version with `python -c 'import tensorflow as tf; print(tf.__version__)'`

Comment: `conda install tensorflow` worked well and `tf.__version__` gave me 2.0.0; however `conda install tensorflow-gpu` did not install properly.

Answer (score 17):

You can now install TF2 for Python 3.7 using conda. You can run the usual

```
$ conda install tensorflow=2.0 python=3.7
```

or

```
$ conda install tensorflow-gpu=2.0 python=3.7
```

for the GPU version.

My preferred approach however would be to manage the dependencies using an `environment.yml` file. You can find examples of how to do this for TF2 and dependencies in these template repos that I created on GitHub.

https://github.com/kaust-vislab/tensorflow-cpu-data-science-project

https://github.com/kaust-vislab/tensorflow-gpu-data-science-project

Comment: probably better to say something like `conda install tensorflow>2` instead of a specific old version

Answer (score 7):

The problem is in `conda install tensorflow`.

`conda` does not have `tensorflow`. You will require to install `tensorflow` using `pip`. You **do not** need to downgrade your Python. It will work with Python 3.7.

Use this

`$ pip install --upgrade tensorflow==2.0.0-beta0`

Since the `beta0` version is released, I mentioned that. You can choose other tf version.

I recommend going through this post on TowardsDataScience: [Step-by-Step Guide to Install Tensorflow 2.0](https://medium.com/p/step-by-step-guide-to-install-tensorflow-2-0-67bc73e79b82?source=email-1c9fae27a83--writer.postDistributed&sk=5af912c052882d0c8d3651cd76b846a9).

This post covers installation steps with `conda`.

Comment: "conda does not have tensorflow", actually it does - but at the time of writing does not have TensorFlow > v1.14

Answer (score 1):

You might want to take a look at this link: https://pypi.org/project/tf-nightly-2.0-preview/#files to see which python version and OS supports your package

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I tried to install tensorflow v2 with `conda install tensorflow` or `conda install tensorflow-gpu` only to get lots of incompatible dependencies.

Just run

`pip install -upgrade tensorflow-gpu`

or

`pip install tensorflow-gpu=2.0.0` for a specific version

Comment: Would be curious to see your error message. I have not had any issues installing TF2 using `conda`. In particular did you try installing into a new environment or did you install into an existing environment? Probably the latter if you were getting errors about incompatible dependencies.

Comment: David, I tried to install TF into a new virtual env. The pip method is just fine.

Comment: Can you post the command that you used and the Conda version? Because I cannot replicate the issues that you are experiencing.

Answer (score 0):

Use ' pip install tensorflow-gpu '. This command does the job - downloads Tensorflow-gpu = 2.4.1

Comment: While this does answer the question, it seems to be duplicating the part of the top voted answer. Also, for conda users it's arguably better to install packages through conda, not through pip

Comment: Unfortunately your answer doesn't add anything to the most voted one. Maybe you can edit it adding more useful info.